# How do I find the matching partial-class in C# & Visual Studio 2010 in a XAML file?

Tags: c#, xaml, partial-classes, base-class

I have an app created with a third-party MVVM framework. I have a bunch of Views that will be essentially the same, so I want to inject a custom class in between my Views and the original framework View base as a new base. But when I do so I get the error, **"Partial declarations of  must not specify different base classes."**

So ideally I'd like to change the other partial to use my newly injected custom base class as its base. But I can't find it anywhere. F12 only brings up my code behind, where the error is being generated once I change the base to my new base, and the XAML file, which has no reference to the original base.

Where is the other partial class? How do I find it? Or am I maybe just going about creating my own base class for a XAML file completely wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I renamed my Silverlight project's namespace and I got the "Cannot resolve symbol '`Initialize Component`'" in my xaml codebehind file:

1. Open the xaml codebehind .cs file where you're having the issue;
2. go to *View-->Class View*, which will open the Class View explorer;
3. in my case, i needed to drill into the namespace that had to be changed,
4. then I clicked on the partial class at issue,
5. then below in a second panel appeared the broken `InitializeComponent` method;
6. double-click on that and the partial class will open with a `.g.i.cs` extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the XAML itself -

The first line of the XAML (the first keyword) defines the type on which you're based (ie: `<Window` or `<UserControl`).  That will likely need to be changed to your base class, as well as the code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is a similar problem to one I've had before.

Your problem may be that the XAML file is declariing your control as a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Your.ExtendedControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!-- other stuff goes here. -->
</UserControl>
```

The above may be what is causing the error. The XAML file needs to use the proper base class as the element tag, like so:

```
<YourNamespace:YourBaseClass x:Class="Your.ExtendedControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:YourNamespace="clr-namespace:Your.Project.Namespace">
    <!-- other stuff goes here -->
</YourNamespace:YourBaseClass>
```